# Dependecy problem when trying to remove emacs

Tags: apt, kubuntu, synaptic

Hello I'm trying to remove emacs - but when I select it for deletion in synaptic - xemacs got selected for an installation. How do I remove emacs and xemacs from my system?

I want to do it, because I use a building age git cloned emacs - and it badly interfere with a system-wide installed.

**Edit**:

I've restarted a computer, unchecked xemacs, unintalled some emacs, than uninstalled all of system-wide emacs.

**Edit 2**:

After i've removed emacs with synaptic, there still were some packages left. I found them by:

```
updatedb # updates locate's database
```

and then have loged the output of

```
locate emacs > log
```

after cleaning some redundund entries I did:

```
cat log | parallel sudo rm -rf # you must have parallel installed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing

```
sudo apt-get purge emacs
```

Comment: I guess You right. Unfortunately - I can not check it - since I've already managed to delete it all. But I'll try to remember `purge`.